# Executing a command thru ssh using pseudo terminal: do not close connection if command is not found

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to write a small script to automate some commands in python for unix and linux, thru pexpect.

Ex:

```
ssh -t sk@192.168.225.22 "uname -r && some_cmd_that_exist_or_not && exec /bin/sh"
```

The problem, is that I don't know from the beginning what type of the OS the machine has, and in some cases the commands are not available.

In this case the connection is closed and a "command not found is returned". I want to continue executing even if a command is not found.

After that I retrive the output using pyexpect. My issue is that I couldn't find an option to keep the connection open if  a commad is not found.

Comment: Just replace the `&&` with `;` eg  `uname -r; some_cmd_that_may_not_exist; exec /bin/sh`

Comment: I tried with ";" but fails also because the command is not found; ";" works for me if the command exist but fails which is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `&&` with `;`:

```
ssh -t sk@192.168.225.22 'uname -r; some_cmd_that_may_not_exist; exec /bin/sh'
```

The `&&` is a short-circuiting operator, so it will stop executing commands as soon as any of the commands fail.  If you want to run them all, just don't use it.

Comment: I tried with ";" but fails also because the command is not found; ";" works for me if the command exist but fails which is different

Comment: If the command does not exist, you will see the error message, but the `exec /bin/sh` should still execute.  Why are you `exec`ing rather than just invoking a shell?

Comment: I want not just to execute the command but maintain the connection and shell, not closing the connection

Comment: A simple `/bin/sh` would accomplish that as well as `exec /bin/sh`.